# how to read large binary data from smartcard iso7816

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

```
            import java.io.File;
            import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
            import java.io.FileOutputStream;
            import java.io.IOException;

            import javax.smartcardio.ATR;
            import javax.smartcardio.Card;
            import javax.smartcardio.CardChannel;
            import javax.smartcardio.CardException;
            import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal;
            import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminals;
            import javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU;
            import javax.smartcardio.ResponseAPDU;
            import javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory;

            @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
            public class APDu {


                static FileOutputStream fos = null;

                private static byte[] SELECT   = { 
                                                    (byte) 0x00,    ////CLA
                                                    (byte) 0xA4,    ////INS
                                                    (byte) 0x04,    ////P1
                                                    (byte) 0x00,    ////P2
                                                    (byte) 0x07,    ////Length of AID
                                                    (byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x43};

                private static byte[] select_dataSet = {
                                                        (byte) 0x00,    ////CLA
                                                        (byte) 0xA4,    ////INS
                                                        (byte) 0x04,    ////P1
                                                        (byte) 0x00,    ////P2
                                                        (byte) 0x01,    ////Length of AID
                                                        (byte) 0x11 };    ///////////worked

                 private static byte[] read_dataSet   = {
                                                        (byte) 0x00,    ////CLA
                                                        (byte) 0xB0,    ////INS
                                                        (byte) 0x00,    ////P1
                                                        (byte) 0x00,    ////P2   this is the offset
                                                        (byte) 0x00,    ////
                                                        (byte) 0x00,
                                                        (byte) 0xFF
                                                        };  

                 private static CommandAPDU SELECT_APDU = new CommandAPDU(SELECT);
                 private static CommandAPDU select_dataSetAPDU = new CommandAPDU(select_dataSet);
                 private static CommandAPDU read_dataSetAPDU = new CommandAPDU(read_dataSet);


                 private static CardTerminal cardTerminal = null;

                 private static void arrayPrint(byte[] data) {
                      System.out.print("{");
                      arrayPrintBytes(data);
                      System.out.print("} (");
                      arrayPrintHex(data);
                      System.out.print(")");
                 }
                 private static void arrayPrintHex(byte[] data) {
                      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                           String bs = Integer.toHexString(data[i] & 0xFF);
                           if (bs.length() == 1)
                                sb.append(0);
                           sb.append(bs).append(" ");
                      }
                      System.out.print( sb.toString() );
                 }
                 private static void arrayPrintBytes(byte[] data) {
                      for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++)
                           System.out.print(data[i]+ " ");
                 }

                 public static boolean sendAPDU(CardChannel ch, CommandAPDU apdu,boolean write) throws CardException {

                      System.out.println("sent these ::: ");arrayPrintHex(apdu.getBytes());
                      ResponseAPDU responseAPDU = ch.transmit(apdu);
                      byte[] response = responseAPDU.getBytes();

                      System.out.print("\n"+responseAPDU.toString()+"  (Nr:"+responseAPDU.getNr() +" SW:"+responseAPDU.getSW()+" SW1:"+responseAPDU.getSW1() +" SW2:"+responseAPDU.getSW2()+")");

                      System.out.print("Bytes received: "); arrayPrint( responseAPDU.getBytes());
                      System.out.print("Data received: ");  arrayPrint( responseAPDU.getData());
                      if(write){

                      }

                      if(write){
                          try {
                              System.out.println("\n\nbytes :::  ");arrayPrintHex(responseAPDU.getData());
                              fos.write(responseAPDU.getData());
                          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                      }


                      //Check if response is 0x9000 (code for success)
                      return (response[response.length - 2] == (byte) 0x90 && response[response.length - 1] == (byte) 0x00);
                 }

                 public APDu() {

                 }

                 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                     File f = new File("dataBytes.dat");

                     fos = new FileOutputStream(f,true);

                     TerminalFactory tf = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
                     CardTerminals ct = tf.terminals();

                     cardTerminal = ct.list().get(0);
                     System.out.println("Selected terminal");

                     if(cardTerminal==null)
                         throw new Exception("ERROR: No cardterminal available to communicate.");
                     try {
                         while (cardTerminal.isCardPresent()) {
                             Card card = null;
                             if ((card = cardTerminal.connect("*")) != null){ 
                                 System.out.println("Connected to card.");
                             } else {
                                 System.out.println("ERROR: Failed to connect to card!"); 
                                 return; 
                             }

                             System.out.print("ATR: "); arrayPrint(((ATR) card.getATR()).getBytes()); System.out.println();

                             CardChannel ch = card.getBasicChannel();

                             //open session
                             if (sendAPDU(ch, SELECT_APDU,false)){
                                 System.out.println("\nReceived data.");
                             } else { 
                                 System.out.println("\nERROR: Unable to get data!"); 
                                 return; 
                             }

                                //select data set
                             if (sendAPDU(ch, select_dataSetAPDU,false)){
                                 System.out.println("\nReceived data.");
                             } else { 
                                 System.out.println("\nERROR: Unable to get data!"); 
                                 return; 
                             }


                             //select read data set
                             if (sendAPDU(ch, read_dataSetAPDU,true)){
                                 System.out.println("\nReceived data.");
                             } else { 
                                 System.out.println("\nERROR: Unable to get data!"); 
                                 return; 
                             }


                             fos.close();
                             return;
                         }
                     } catch (CardException e) {
                         System.out.println("Error isCardPresent()" + e.getCause());
                     }
                 }


            }
```

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvQHZ.png

In the above link :

the data on the left is the actual data which im supposed to read from the smartcard and the other side one is the data which i read from the card. 
im able to read only 255 bytes out of 326 bytes ::::

from 00-255 data and 2 bytes status word

how can i read the remaining bytes.

========================================================================
The below is the output of my code:

Selected terminal
Connected to card.
ATR: {59 -1 -107 0 -1 -64 10 49 -2 77 -128 49 -32 107 4 32 5 2 82 85 85 85 85 85 85 -106 } (3b ff 95 00 ff c0 0a 31 fe 4d 80 31 e0 6b 04 20 05 02 52 55 55 55 55 55 55 96 )

Command ::: 00 a4 04 00 07 a0 00 00 00 34 49 44 43   --- command to open session
ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=9000  (Nr:0 SW:36864 SW1:144 SW2:0)Bytes received: {-112 0 } (90 00 )Data received: {} ()
Received data.

command ::: 00 a4 04 00 01 11       ---command to select header id : 11
ResponseAPDU: 25 bytes, SW=9000  (Nr:23 SW:36864 SW1:144 SW2:0)Bytes received: {1 17 6 94 1 70 1 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -112 0 } (01 11 06 5e 01 46 01 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 )Data received: {1 17 6 94 1 70 1 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 } (01 11 06 5e 01 46 01 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 )
Received data.

command ::: 00 b0 00 00 00 00 ff    --- command to read
ResponseAPDU: 257 bytes, SW=9000  (Nr:255 SW:36864 SW1:144 SW2:0)

06 5e is the max data to receive and 01 46 is the available data. i already read 255 bytes i just need to read remaining 44 bytes. what would be the next offset to retrieve the remaining bytes.

Comment: You must change the applet too. Check Vojta's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415519/failed-to-send-extended-apdu). It's exactly what you want to have :)

Comment: thanks everyone for the help...im able to read all the bytes now.

Comment: How did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Extended APDU allows large amounts of data to be sent to the card, processed appropriately, and sent back to the terminal, in a more efficient way. Instead of having to re-issue multiple APDU messages to complete an operation requiring large volumes of data, and requiring the developer to code the application to keep a state across such multiple APDU commands, extended APDU allows applets to perform this function more efficiently with one large APDU exchange.

Use [this reference](http://askra.de/software/jcdocs/app-notes-2.2.2/extapdu.html) for more information.

**UPDATE:**

In this Reference there's a step by step guid to write an applet that takes advantage of extended length. Note that the applet should implements `javacardx.apdu.ExtendedLength` interface.

Also you can use `C0 00 00 XX` which XX is usually the `SW2` of the prevoious answer. That's because the card is using `T=0` protocol.

For example if the response is `61 09` then send `00 C0 00 00 09` until the response become `90 00`. of course each time you should replace `XX` with the previous response.

Comment: Hey! You okay Mrs BzH? :) --- The APDU command that the questioner sent to card to read is an Extended form APDU command, and as he/she successfully received 255 bytes, it doesn't mean that he/she implemented Extended interface in the applet? Does regular applets accept Extended form APDU commands that read/write short data?

Comment: @Abraham thanks for the comment

Answer (score -1):

To read large binary data > 255 bytes, you have to implement chaining protocol.
Please check below links:

[Reading big file from a javacard applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645679/reading-big-file-from-a-javacard-applet)

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2207556?tstart=0

Comment: >255 is different from large; simply specifying the offset in P1/P2 will do, no extended length necessary

Comment: who said extended ?? I said chaining NOT extended. Which will require specifying P1/P2 and also some code in Javacard to handle incoming data.

Comment: If you don't have further confusion on this, please remove -ive point.

Comment: I see no point in implementing chaining if extended length was not intended. Admittedly *chaining* is used in lot of different contexts, but in my accepted answer to the question of your first link it is **not** used. I fail to see, which benefit the second link provides to the question.